# Hover Animation Not Completed

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

Here is a fiddle for illustration purposes:
http://jsfiddle.net/wVRtL/

HTML:

```
    <section class="full-w blue">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="two"></div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="full-w red">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="two"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

jQuery

```
$('.full-w').hover(function() {
   marginTopHero = $(this).find('.two').css("margin-top").replace("px", "");
   newMargin = marginTopHero - 50 + "px";
   oldMargin = marginTopHero + "px";

   $(this).find('.two').stop().animate({ 'margin-top': newMargin }, 'fast');
   }, function() {
   $(this).find('.two').stop().animate({ 'margin-top': oldMargin }, 'fast');
});
```

[image]

The expected behavior is that when hovering over the line, the yellow rectangle moves up, and moves back down to its original position when the mouse leaves the line. But if you move your pointer very quickly from one red line to another, your will see that the yellow box lifts up gradually until it hits the top of the line.

[image]

I have to retrieve the margin-top value of this element to be able to revert to that position on mouseleave (the margin-top will vary from one .two to another)

I understand this is a tricky, unless I am totally missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be you are saving the old value in a shared global variable, use the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) api instead to save the previous valud

```
$('.full-w').hover(function() {

    var marginTopHero = $(this).find('.two').css("margin-top").replace("px", "");
    var newMargin = marginTopHero - 150 + "px";
    $(this).data('oldMargin', marginTopHero + "px")

    $(this).find('.two').stop().animate({ 'margin-top': newMargin }, 'fast');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.two').stop().animate({ 'margin-top': $(this).data('oldMargin') }, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: I think the issue is I am retrieving the margin-top every time there is a hover, and I should only store the first instance.